# Problema con html2pdf.js

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy intentando hacer un pdf con la librería html2pdf.js. El problema es que cuando hay varias páginas, no las corta bien, incluso corta la frase por la mitad. ¿Cómo puedo hacer bien el salto de página? Gracias. Os pongo el código:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var presupuesto_pdf = document.getElementById('pdf_presupuesto').innerHTML;
    
    html2pdf()
    
    .set({
        margin: [1, 1, 5, 1],
        filename: '<?php echo $nombre_archivo;?>',
        image:{type:'png'},
        pagebreak: { mode: ['avoid-all', 'css', 'legacy'] },
        html2canvas: {
            scale: 1,
            letterRendering: true,
        },
        jsPDF: {
            unit: "mm",
            format: "A4",
            orientation: 'portrait'
        }
    })
    
    .from(presupuesto_pdf)
    .save();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ingresas  especificas el elemento que quieres que no se corte ejemplo lo utilice con una tabla.

**Nota : deben importar la libreria html2pdf y sus respectivo codigo js para su respectivo funcionamiento**

Documentación: https://www.html2pdf.co.uk/api-documentation

---

// SE AGREGA EN EL JS

```
 pagebreak: {avoid: 'tr'}

 <tr>
  <td> </td>
 <tr>
```

---

otra solucion es agragar este style

```
     .page_break {
      page-break-before: always;
    }

  <tr class="page_break" ></tr>
```

Que añade un salto de página siempre antes de esa fila de la tabla.